# "Top Posts" depending on facebook likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an idea to create a "top posts" feature to my website, which creates the "top" list depending on how many likes and shares that a post have on facebook.

Users may see how many likes an post has received so far since they only have to ask for a single, defined url. However, the website itself has to be able to query all the links that are tied to itself (which have a predefined url template like website.com/[post-id]) to create the "top" list. Is it possible to do something similar (or achieve the same result in a different way)?

Any ideas on a real workflow about something like this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a little but interesting project. I don't know if there is a feature that could get that directly in the way you want, but i did something similar.

First you have the Graph API, with that you can get the Posts of a user using `feed`, with that every post is telling you how many likes does it have which you can get with `POST_ID/likes`.

Then you'll have to check for changes in the post periodically comparing its `created_time` and `updated_time`.

This could seem very hard, because you have a lot of posts and you have to check them all for updates, but you can use `batch_requests` so you can check them all at once.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. When "Graph API" is used in a way you've mentioned, I need the users to "connect with facebook", right ? What I need in my project is something quite different in that manner, I do not really wish to do any connections to the facebook user; I only want to display the order by using the like/share count.

Comment: There will be a lot of entries to order (that's right! - thousands) and do you know if "batch requests" have any limitations?

Comment: Yes, you'll need the permission of the user, so they have to login in your page. The limits are here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ , in the *limits* section

Comment: Oh, I try to look at it like this: "like count" is public so maybe there is a way to evaluate posts with that count if there is any way to reach it.

Comment: We once did an app where we wanted to get as much information as possible (not only of our friends), so we got the posts of public pages, yes they are most public, but you still need an access_token. this access_token can be the simplest one (minimum permissions).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a bookmarklet which shows top posts in the Facebook News Feed as well as Google+, Twitter and Instagram Profiles.

Just add a new bookmark in your bookmarks bar and replace its URL with the following code and save it, then go to the social network website and run it:

```
javascript:(function(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.src='https://niutech.github.io/topnewsfeed/topnewsfeed.min.js';document.body.appendChild(s);})()
```

The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/niutech/topnewsfeed).